# convert datetime string to UTC date time java

Tags: java, datetime

```
String date_Value=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
String startDateUTC=DateTime.SpecifyKind(date_Value,DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

i want both the values current date time and UTC both in Two string values

Comment: Is your question about Java? That second line looks like C# code, it's using .NET API classes and methods.

Comment: Are you saying you want to perform the equivalent .NET calls in Java?

Comment: Can you provide example of what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: In date_Value string i have the locale time. I want to convert this date_Value string (local) datetime to UTC time

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");     formatUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateTime=formatUTC.format(new Date()); How can I convert This time to IST